# Floating an li's :after right in IE10/9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am trying to float an li's :after, which includes a background element. 
It works in every browser on Mac, and every browser on Win, EXCEPT IE. 
I tried changing around parameters like the display and floating, which does not work.

**CSS:**

```
ul.nav li a:after { 
    background: url(images/nav_icon.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 8px; 
    height: 5px; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    margin: 8px 0 0 6px; 
}
```

Heres what it looks like right:

[image]

Heres what IE does:

[image]

I am thankful for any help. Only thing i found googling was clearfix tricks for IE7, nothing regarding how that stupid browser interpretes selectors.

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need to float it at all since it will always appear after the `a` links content. I think we need a JSfiddle to get a grasp on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using conditional comments which contain `display: inline-block` and removing the floating for the :after.